# Ionic: How to create tabs with ion-tabs without icons?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework and want to create tabs without icons. I know I can achieve this with the CSS component tabs (http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs). Just wanted to check if it's possible with ion-tab directive also (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/). I tried with ion-tab directive by not providing the icon attribute. It creates the tab, but the placeholder of the icon is still there and the tabs don't look good with that empty space in place of the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 <ion-content scroll="false">
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top">
          <ion-tab title="Home" href="#">                
            <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>
          <ion-tab title="Gallery" href="#">
            <ion-nav-view name="gallery"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>        
    </ion-tabs> 
 </ion-content>
```